# How to search domains with common code or template?

Tags: search, joomla, joomla3.0

I need to search for other domains on the internet that share a certain part of code in the index file of the home page or in .css or .js files. or even an entire Joomla template. How can I do this ?

Explanation: the Joomla 3 template (Shape5 Traction) I use for my site will not be updated by the developers to support Joomla 4, unless there is a request from several owners of the template. I therefore want to find and contact other owners of the same template to see if they are interested in sharing the migration costs.

Answer (score 0):

Download what do you want master folder from FTP, exp [template folder]
then load folder into your local editor aka Notepad++ or Sublime, search your query from `Ctrl + F` or `SHIFT + CTRL + F` in editor. The result will appear from all file contains query. You will know the path from query.

Comment: I would like to point out that the search should not be in files locally, but in Internet domains belonging to third parties ...